# How to get hidden columns in jQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

`jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel')` does not return the currently hidden columns.

```
colNames:[ ' Group Id ' ,'Group Title','No. of Participants','Comment','Date Of Creation','Last Modified'], 
colModel:[
{name:'participant_group_id',index:'1',editrules:{required:false,email:false,number:false},search:true,width:0,key:true, hidden:true, editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions: {size:30}},
{name:'participant_group_title',index:'2',formoptions:{elmprefix:'<font color="red">*</font>'},editrules:{required:true,email:false,number:false},search:true,width:150,key:false, hidden:false, editable:true,edittype:"text",editoptions: {size:30}},
{name:'number_of_group_participants',index:'3',editrules:{required:false,email:false,number:false},search:true,width:125,key:false, hidden:false, editable:false,edittype:"text",editoptions: {size:30}},
{name:'comment',index:'4',editrules:{required:false,email:false,number:false},search:true,width:135,key:false, hidden:false, editable:true,edittype:"textarea",editoptions: {rows:"5",cols:"28"}},
{name:'group_created_date_time',index:'5',editrules:{required:false,email:false,number:false},search:true,width:135,key:false, hidden:false, editable:false,edittype:"text",editoptions: {size:60}},
{name:'group_updated_date_time',index:'6',editrules:{required:false,email:false,number:false},search:true,width:120,key:false, hidden:false, editable:false,edittype:"text",editoptions: {size:60}}],
```

`jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel')` returns the last 5 columns

```
colModel
(5) […]
​
0: Object { name: "participant_group_title", index: "2", search: true, … }
​
1: Object { name: "number_of_group_participants", index: "3", search: true, … }
​
2: Object { name: "comment", index: "4", search: true, … }
​
3: Object { name: "group_created_date_time", index: "5", search: true, … }
​
4: Object { name: "group_updated_date_time", index: "6", search: true, … }
​
length: 5
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

How to get the hidden column? Is there a way to get the details of the hidden column? Let me know of a mechanism to get the details of the hidden column.

Comment: `jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel')` return all the columns in jqGrid including the hidden one. I recommend you either to look into your code or to look in  your browser setting in order to see if console.log is configured to return only 5 items. Please let me know which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: You are right. There was a problem in my understanding. I have added the code in the answer with the hope that it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where I was fetching the Column Model from the jQGrid object and trying to identify the hidden columns so that they do not show up in the generated Excel. Note I am using a server-side solution here for generating the JSON from MySQL.

```
function exportToExcel(interface_id, part_id){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "./interfaceenginev2.GetJSONforGrid",
        data: "interface_id=" + interface_id + "&part_id=" + part_id,

        success: function (data)
        {
            var colNames = $('#' + part_id).jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colNames');
            var colModel = $('#' + part_id).jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'colModel');

            for( var i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++){ 
                 if ( colModel[i].hidden === true) {
                        var name = colModel[i].name;
                        delete data[i][name];
                        colNames.splice(i, 1); 
                        colModel.splice(i, 1);                 
                 }
            }
            $.unblockUI();


            var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
            var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref']);
            for(var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
              var address = XLSX.utils.encode_col(C) + "1"; 
              if(!ws[address]) continue;
              ws[address].v = colNames[C];
            }

            var wscols = [];
            colModel.forEach(function (column) {
                wscols.push({wpx:column.width});
            });
            ws["!cols"] = wscols;
            var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, interface_id);
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, part_id + ".xlsx" );
       },
        error: function (xhr) {
            $.unblockUI();
            alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);                
        }
    });
}

This code is working now!
```

Comment: There is a bug in the above code. I am giving the corrected code below

Comment: var hiddenColumns = [];
         for( var i = 0; i < colModel.length; i++){ 
           if ( colModel[i].hidden === true) {
            hiddenColumns.push(colModel[i].name);
                   colNames.splice(i, 1); 
                   colModel.splice(i, 1);              
           }
         }
         
         for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
             for( var j = 0; j < hiddenColumns.length; j++){
              var hiddenColumnName = hiddenColumns[j];
              delete data[i][hiddenColumnName];
             }
         }